# hibernate .hbm.xml file mapping error

Tags: hibernate, maven, mapping

eventhough I have correctly structured my project, when I am getting error in mapping Employee.hbm.xml as below:

here is my Exception code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.viralpatel.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:16)
    at net.viralpatel.hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at net.viralpatel.hibernate.Main.list(Main.java:26)
    at net.viralpatel.hibernate.Main.main(Main.java:75)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: net/viralpatel/hibernate/Employee.hbm.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:738)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2188)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2160)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2140)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2093)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2008)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1987)
    at net.viralpatel.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java)
```

Any suggestion for this..

Comment: how did you create the project?

Comment: Can you post..`Employee.hbm.xml` and `hibernate.cfg.xml`...The exception shows that the `Employee.hbm.xml` not found while execution

Comment: What is the path of Employee.hbm.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml ?

Answer (score 1):

**Check the mapping class configuration in** `Hibernate.cfg.xml`.

You have mapped the `Employee.hbm.xml` in `cfg.xml` but mentioned path not found, Ensure that the `Employee.hbm.xml` is available in correct path..

**Eg.**

In `hibernate.cfg.xml`

`<mapping class="pojo.Holidays" resource="pojo/Holidays.hbm.xml"/>`

Here the `Holidays.hbm.xml` is under `pojo` directory, if the `xml` is not available under `pojo` directory, it will show the above `Exception`

Answer (score 0):

So what

```
org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource:
net/viralpatel/hibernate/Employee.hbm.xml not found
```

means is that a file called "Employee.hbm.xml" is not being picked up on the classpath.

Check that:

- you have a file with this name (capitalization is important)
- this file is in a directory structure of `net/viralpatel/hibernate`
- the `net` directory is on the classpath (for example, in `WEB-INF/classes` if
  you're running a webapp)